# Kinematics constant acceleration problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

> A stone is being thrown vertically upward with a speed of 12.5m/s from the edge of a cliff 75.0m high, what’s the total distance did it travel?

It is a constant acceleration kinematics problem, I used $v^2=u^2+2aS$ ,
and I understand that the value of $v$ is $0$ because at max height $v=0$, however, my final answer is wrong, how do I approach this question?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Calculate the time it takes for speed of the stone to be zero (Hint: use equation $v = v_0 + at$, where t is time, a the constant acceleration and v_0 the initial speed. Keep in mind the acceleration points down so $a = -9,81 m/s^2$)

Step 2: You now know the time it takes for the speed of the rock to become zero. You can now calculate the distance it has traveled vertically upward during that time. (Hint: use $x(t) = x_0 + v_0t + \frac{a}{2}t^2$ and take $x_0$ to be zero for obvious reasons, for t you use the time you got from step 1)

Step 3: The rock travels that distance, calculated in step 2, two times. The first time when you trow it up and the second time when it comes down. So now you can calculate the total distance (keep in mind the 75 m)

I hope this helps :)).